# LoadBalanced WebClient together with Eureka WebClient enabled

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, netflix-eureka

In a reactive microservice I'm registering to Eureka and using a `@LoadBalanced` WebClient to get a response from an instance. Registering in Eureka alone works, but once I add the `@LoadBalanced` WebClient I get following error.

```
2021-05-22 14:31:14.835  INFO 1852 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2021-05-22 14:31:14.985 ERROR 1852 --- [           main] scoveryClientServiceInstanceListSupplier : Exception occurred while retrieving instances for service 127.0.0.1

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.eurekaClient': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:274) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
```

I assume it is related to the configuration  `eureka.client.webclient.enabled=true`.

#### The Application

That's my application and the crucial parts of its configuration.

*application.yml*

```yaml
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${vcap.services.eureka-service.credentials.uri:http://127.0.0.1:8761}/eureka/
    webclient:
      enabled: true
```

*ConsumerApplication.java*

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConsumerApplication {

    public Mono<ServerResponse> handler(ServerRequest request) {
        return webClientBuilder()
                .baseUrl("http://producer")
                .build()
                .get()
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.just("Error " + e.getMessage()))
                .flatMap(r -> ok().bodyValue(Map.of("Producer says", r)));
    }

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder(){
        return WebClient.builder();
    }

    @Bean
    RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routes() {
        return route()
                .GET("", this::handler)
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConsumerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

#### Eureka WebClient disabled

If instead `eureka.client.webclient.enabled=false` is used, everything works perfectly fine. However, I don't think this should be the solution.

```
DiscoveryClientOptionalArgsConfiguration : Eureka HTTP Client uses RestTemplate.
```

How would I go about using a `@LoadBalanced` WebClient together with `eureka.client.webclient.enabled=true`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same problem, this is how I fixed it.

```
@Bean
@LoadBalanced
public WebClient.Builder lbWebClient() {
    return WebClient.builder();
}

@Bean
@Primary
public WebClient.Builder webClient() {
    return WebClient.builder();
}
```

Use @Qualifier later on to used the loadbalanced one.

Comment: can u provife more explaination on your solution?