# I can't access the service through its application.name - Eureka

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

Eureka Sever registers all my services, however when trying to access them through their application.name I cannot, I have tried RestTemplate and OpenFeign but it has not been possible in any way.

[image]

When FEATURES-SERVICE requests an image from IMAGES-SERVICE through: http://localhost:9005 work, but when FEATURES-SERVICE requests an image from IMAGES-SERVICE through: http://images-service fail.

This is my config for eureka-server:

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: false
    register-with-eureka: false
```

and config for features-service and images-service

```
// IMAGES-SERVICE
server:
  port:9005
spring:
  application:
    name: images-service

eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
    instance:
      hostname: localhost 

// FEATURES-SERVICE
server:
  port:9004
spring:
  application:
    name: features-service

eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
    instance:
      hostname: localhost
```

both services has the annotation @EnableEurekaClient in the Application file.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue while using rest template and calling the other service, I got it running using the annotation `@LoadBalanced` on RestTemplate bean in my application class.

Comment: I'm already using it but I'm still facing the same issue, infact I replaced service-name with acutal IP and then it started claiming that it is also not found

Comment: Little note: The RestClient is deprecated, so if you  want to use WebClient instead - here is the solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67649680/loadbalanced-webclient-together-with-eureka-webclient-enabled

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the same as what is suggested here in the answer (adding @LoadBalanced) for the restTemplate injector but it wasn't working for me.

I had written the gateway controller in the Eureka Server itself to receive request from front end and redirect it to other micro-services.
When I wrote whole new application to work as gateway service, everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have Ribbon added as a dependency in your pom.xml file OR you are getting exception from Ribbon. If this is the case remove the Ribbon from your project.