# LoadBalanced WebClient seems to want my RouteLocator. What for?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

Look, this code doesn't work:

```java
package com.example.gatewaydemo.routing;

import org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalanced;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Optional;

@Configuration
public class MyRoutingConfig {
    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder() {
        return WebClient.builder();
    }
    @Bean
    public RouteLocator routeLocator(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder, RouteLocatorBuilder routeLocatorBuilder) {
        Optional<String> string = webClientBuilder.build()
                .get()
                .uri("https://example.com")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .blockOptional(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        return routeLocatorBuilder.routes()
                .route(predicateSpec -> predicateSpec
                        .path("/uuid")
                        .uri("https://httpbin.org/uuid")
                ).build();
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>gatewaydemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>gatewaydemo</name>
    <description>gatewaydemo</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
2023-12-04T07:18:40.404+03:00 ERROR 14220 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  routeLocator defined in class path resource [com/example/gatewaydemo/routing/MyRoutingConfig.class]
↑     ↓
|  corsGatewayFilterApplicationListener defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gateway/config/GatewayAutoConfiguration.class]
↑     ↓
|  routePredicateHandlerMapping defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gateway/config/GatewayAutoConfiguration.class]
↑     ↓
|  cachedCompositeRouteLocator defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gateway/config/GatewayAutoConfiguration.class]
└─────┘


Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.
```

To get it to work, you need to do one of the two things (or both):

1. Remove the `@LoadBalanced` annotation
2. Remove the asynchronous request to `example.com` (it could be any domain)

It seems a `@LoadBalanced` `WebClient` for some reason wants a `RouteLocator` in a Gateway application

In the actual application, I use Eureka, and one [could suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67649680/loadbalanced-webclient-together-with-eureka-webclient-enabled) the problem may have to do with that. However, as you see, I reproduced the issue even without Eureka

It has relevance since in my project, I [use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77563031/cant-refresh-a-refresh-scoped-routelocator) a `WebClient` to dynamically build routes in runtime. It has to be a `@LoadBalanced` `WebClient` since it should be able to resolve microservice names

What is happening and what are the solutions/workarounds?